# PHP - returning data from a function

Tags: php, function, return

Can anyone spot a light where am I going wrong?

This is the objective of the program:
**To make a program that has a function that is passed 3 quiz scores and returns the average of the top 2 scores.**

```
<?php
  function average ($quiz1, $quiz2, $quiz3) {
    $quiz1 = 100;
    $quiz2 = 50;
    $quiz3 = 80;

    $average1 = $quiz1 + $quiz3 / 2;
    $average2 = $quiz2 + $quiz3 / 2;
    $average3 = $quiz3 + $quiz1 / 2;

    echo $average1;
    echo $average2;
    echo $average3;

    return ($average);
  }

  echo max ($average1, $average2, $average3);
  average (100, 50, 80);

?>
```

Comment: You're returning `$average` from your function, but don't have an actual variable called `$average` in the function to return.

Comment: You don't call the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function would take your `3 quiz scores and return the average of the top 2 scores.`

It puts the 3 scores into an array, then reverse sorts them (greatest to least). Then it takes the first two items (the greatest) and provides the average of them both.

```
function average($quiz1, $quiz2, $quiz3) {

    $scores = [$quiz1,$quiz2,$quiz3];
    rsort($scores);
    return ($scores[0] + $scores[1]) / 2;

}
```

Example:

```
echo average(50,100,150);
```

Result:

**125**